# Woocommerce REST api with OAuth 1.0a one-legged

Tags: ios, rest, oauth, woocommerce

I'm doing the iOS app that uses the Woocommerce REST api. Because i don't have ssl on my server so i need to use the OAuth 1.0a one-legged to call them ([documentation](http://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce/rest-api/)). I'm using the [AFOAuth1Client](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFOAuth1Client%20AFOAuth1Client), my code is:

```
AFOAuth1Client *twitterClient = [[AFOAuth1Client alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://128.199.175.238"] key:@"ck_b2d3e723f46c5c02c363f39337c25306" secret:@"cs_01fce1d081ae22651472855a0d0bca8a"];

NSURLRequest *request = [twitterClient requestWithMethod:@"GET" path:@"/wc-api/v1/products" parameters:nil];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [twitterClient HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

}];

[twitterClient enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];
```

but I always get the error with output:

{"errors":[{"code":"woocommerce_api_authentication_error","message":"oauth_consumer_key parameter is missing"}]}

So I wonder that did i do something wrongly?

Comment: I actually figured out myself. We need go to AFOAuth1Client to modify to adapt OAuth 1.0a one-legged.

Comment: Your new working code would be very useful.

Comment: I am having this exact same issue and having a bad time modifying AFOAUth client...

Comment: @Jeremie did you success when try to "create" method?

Comment: If it is working for you, can you give me steps in detail to change it as I always getting error in response for a week

Comment: in short, here is my repo https://github.com/khanghoang/-WooClient, feel free to get it if it fits yours

Comment: Thanks @trieukhang  ,it really saved my lots of time worked fine for me :)

Comment: Np, it took me days to figure out :)